# Three.js export option is sometimes disabled

Tags: export, three.js

I'm trying to export models from some format (`.obj`, `.3ds`, `.blend`) to `Three.js` but sometimes they can't be exported. Can someone explain why?

This is what happens:

[image: Screenshot of disabled three.js export option]

The `Three.js` option in the export menu can't be selected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Blender there is a difference between **active** and **selected**,
typically its fine to think of active as *last selected*.

Notice when you select the object, its outline (or wire) color is brighter then other selected objects.

The `poll` only succeeds (i.e., the operator is only enabled) if `bpy.context.active_object != None`: see [`io_mesh_threejs/__init__.py:323`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/blender/2.66/scripts/addons/io_mesh_threejs/__init__.py#L323).

This will be the case right after you deleted an object, imported models (e.g. OBJ) or certain operator calls. These operations can clear the `active_object`, although objects may still be selected.

Select any object (or set `active_object` to an object with python) before you open the *File > Export* panel.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't `bpy.context.active_object != None` mean that there *is* an active object?

Comment: @gandalf3 You are correct, but that is also what CoDEmanx is saying. The 'poll' function returns true if there is an active object, false if not. A difference of semantics perhaps.

Comment: @kaliatech I would think it would fail if `bpy.context.active_object = None`, as opposed to `!= None`, but I may be wrong.

Comment: It should actually be `return context.active_object is not None` instead of `!=`, but it basically does the same (and right) thing. If there's an active object, it evaluates to True. `poll()` needs to return True if all conditions to run the operator are met. If there's no `active_object`, `poll()` returns False and the menu entry will be grayed out.

Comment: @CoDEmanX I've edited your post to write what I think you meant to say; please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: I didn't notice at all! Thanks for editing, was bad logic. Also thank you ideasman for your addition!

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the *Properties editor* in your screenshot I can see that the panels that should appear when a mesh is active (*Modifiers*, *Constraints*, *Object* and *Data* etc.) are missing.

This shows that you don't actually have an active object.

Note that there is a difference between a *selected* object and an *active* object, see the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Selecting#Selections_and_the_Active_Object). Notice that the object in the middle of the scene has an orange outline, this means that it is *selected*. *Active* objects have a lighter orange outline.

I would think that the exporter might be able to tell and so disables itself.

Try making the object active by right clicking on it, then try the export again.

Comment: I edited your answer to better explain the differences between `active` and `selected`. Please [rollback](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing) if you don't agree with my edits.